# AS3: Using embedded font

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, fonts

I embed font like this (FlashDevelop):

```
[ Embed( source = "Ubuntu-R.ttf", embedAsCFF = "false", fontFamily = "Ubuntu" ) ]
private static const Ubuntu : Class;
```

Then try to use like this:

```
var textField : TextField = new TextField;
textField.embedFonts = true;
textField.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat( "Ubuntu", 22 );
textField = "免費旋轉 ПРИВЕТ HELLO";
addChild( textField );
```

Only russian and english parts of the text visible, but not japanese (my PC is russian). If to comment **textField.embedFonts = true;** line, then the whole text will be visible, but some other (seems like Arial) font used.

Call to **Font.enumerateFonts( false );** returns array with one font called "Ubuntu".

Call to **Font.registerFont( Ubuntu );** at any place doesn't help.

Adding parameters **fontName**, **unicodeRange = "U+0000-U+FFFF"**, **mimeType = "application/x-font-truetype"**, **fontWeight**, **advancedAntiAliasing** to the font embed directive with different attributes do not change the behavior.

Seems like dead end, but please help.

Comment: What would `Font.enumerateFonts(false)[0].hasGlyphs(textField.text)` return?

Comment: It returns "false", hmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font you use does not contain the required glyphs for Japanese. You might try another font, make sure though it has enough glyphs in there. A hint: if the font isn't as big as 1 megabyte, most likely it has neither japanese nor chinese glyphs, if it's bigger, then try embedding and check with `hasGlyphs()` if it has enough. Once you'll find the correct font, embed and enjoy. But, I'd say use a font that's widely distributed and has japanese glyphs by design, say Arial.